# Gravatar HiDPI in Chat

Tags: bug, chat, profile-picture, gravatar, retina

I have been noticing this bug. While the recent update renders all profile pics Retina-ready (HiDPI), the Gravatar-based profiles are still blurry on a Retina Display. Here is a screenshot:

[image: profile]

Also, if the profile picture is uploaded directly to StackExchange, then it loses alpha channel (transparency), so currently it's impossible to have a picture which has transparency *and* sharpness everywhere.

Please address this issue.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

I just noticed: Meta doesn't support this too.

[image: meta bug]

Comment: Hey, that's me!

Comment: Hey, that's also me.